# ios google maps dont allow to add images onto it

Tags: ios, google-maps, imageview, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to put static image using imageview on google maps. but its not displaying that image. so there is any idea to put up imageview on google map ?  thanks in advance. plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ground overlay or marker (depending on if you want it to scale with the map or not), but these both use a `UIImage`, not a `UIImageView`.